# Is there anyway to "inject" code with reflection into static classes?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, custom-attributes

I'm trying to make the creation of cache-proxy classes as easy as possible. I've been through a few different experiments with an easy API for it, but it's not that easy.

Right now, I'm looking at attributes and reflection to see if it can be "magically" resolved. For instance, given this class:

```
public static MyCache
{
  [Cache("foobar")]
  public static string Foobar { get; set; }
}
```

and have it somehow churn out the equivalent to

```
public static MyCache
{
  [Cache("foobar")]
  public static string Foobar
  {
    get
    {
      return (string)Cacher.Get("foobar");
    }
    set
    {
      Cacher.Set("foobar", value, new CacheOptions()); //or whatever
    }
  }
}
```

While both versions should look "normal" to the caller so that this is valid:

```
MyCache.Foobar="meh";
Assert.IsEqual("meh", MyCache.Foobar);
```

Is there anything available to me with reflection that would make something like this work?

Comment: Reflection allows you to inquire about a limited set of aspects of the program, and to execute some other set of limited actions.  What that set is determined by the language implementers. But none of these actions actually modify the program.  If you want a solution that can generate program source code, you need something other than reflection.  If you would  like, I can elaborate as an answer.

Comment: @IraBaxter I know about code generation and post-processing. I've been trying to avoid it though if at all possible because of the extra steps required in building and setup of new projects

Comment: If you want to produce new code, you need a tool that generate that code.  Reflection isn't it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything available to me with reflection that would make something like this work?

No, there's nothing available to achieve that, especially if the property is not virtual. If the property is virtual you could use frameworks like [Castle.DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) to do Aspect Oriented Programming. Popular mocking frameworks such as Rhino Mocks and NSubstitute use it in order to generate runtime proxy objects. Of course this only works with virtual members. In the example you have shown you have a static property which cannot be weaved.

You could use post compilation processing tools such as [`PostSharp`](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) to achieve that. They work by modifying the generated IL.

Comment: Well, I've been trying to avoid that. I also had a T4 template which did code generation, but I'd like to avoid such a thing if possible

Comment: I am afraid that this is not possible.

Comment: So possibly using a singleton pattern where the properties are virtual could make this possible? I imagine that would not be easy to implement at all though

Comment: If the member is virtual `Castle.DynamicProxy` could help you. Check that out: http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2009/02/14/Simple-AOP-call-interception-with-DynamicProxy.aspx You might also consider reading the official documentation: http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: There are other tools that directly modify the source, rather than the IL.